# Python Dataframe Rolling median with group by

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, median

I have a dataframe with three columns, viz., `date`,`commodity` and `values`. I want to add another column, `median_20`, the rolling median of last 20 days for each `commodity` in the `df`. Also, I want to add other columns which show value `n` days before, for example, `lag_1` column shows value 1 day before for a given `commodity`, `lag_2` shows value 2 days before, and so on. My `df` is quite big (>2 million rows) in size.

```
dates = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-07-02')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'commodity':np.random.normal(size = len(dates)), 'market':'GOLD'})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'commodity':np.random.normal(size = len(dates)), 'market':'SILVER'})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df = df.sort('date')

          date  commodity     value
0   2017-01-01       GOLD -1.239422
0   2017-01-01     SILVER -0.209840
1   2017-01-02     SILVER  0.146293
1   2017-01-02       GOLD  1.422454
2   2017-01-03       GOLD  0.453222
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dataframe
dates = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-07-02')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'commodity':np.random.normal(size = len(dates)), 'market':'GOLD'})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'commodity':np.random.normal(size = len(dates)), 'market':'SILVER'})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df = df.sort_values(by='date').reset_index(drop=True)

# create columns
df['median_20_temp'] = df.groupby('market')['commodity'].rolling(20).median()
df['median_20'] = df.groupby('market')['median_20_temp'].shift(1)
df['lag_1'] = df.groupby('market')['commodity'].shift(1)
df['lag_2'] = df.groupby('market')['commodity'].shift(2)
df.drop(['median_20_temp'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

#### Edit:

The following should work with version `0.16.2`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


np.random.seed(123)
dates = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-07-02')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'commodity':np.random.normal(size = len(dates)), 'market':'GOLD'})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'commodity':np.random.normal(size = len(dates)), 'market':'SILVER'})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df = df.sort('date').reset_index(drop=True)

# create columns
df['median_20_temp'] = df.groupby('market')['commodity'].apply(lambda s: pd.rolling_median(s, 20))
df['median_20'] = df.groupby('market')['median_20_temp'].shift(1)
df['lag_1'] = df.groupby('market')['commodity'].shift(1)
df['lag_2'] = df.groupby('market')['commodity'].shift(2)
df.drop(['median_20_temp'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Abdou. I tried this but it throws `AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'rolling'`. In my office we use version '0.16.2' of pandas and unfortunately it is not easy to upgrade it in our production env. This is the error while executing first statement -`df['median_20'] = ...`

Comment: The second & third statements throws following error - `pandas/core/groupby.py, line 581, in wrapper raise ValueError    ValueError`

Comment: @Gerry unfortunately I can't debug the code for data I cannot see. I'm working with the data you provided here. Please share the data that's throwing those errors. Also, make sure that you're using the latest version of pandas.

Comment: I am getting these errors with the above data frame. As you rightly pointed out that these are related to the version of pandas I am using. Unfortunately it is not easy for me to get pandas upgraded in our office production env.

Comment: `lag_1` and `lag_2` statements work fine. However with `median_20` statement somehow it is not giving correct results. It is not failing but if you check the results these are not medians of previous 20 values in `commodities` column.

Comment: @Gerry, that may be because I am using `as_index=False` also `resetting` the indices. Changing that may give the correct values. See the changes.

Comment: This works now. Just a small step to match with exact requirements. Replace `median_20` with `median_20_temp` and then shift forward by 1 using `df['median_20'] = df.groupby('market')['median_20_temp'].shift(1)`. And finally `df.drop(['median_20_temp'], axis=1, inplace=True)`. Thanks a lot @Abdou. This is very helpful.

Comment: @Gerry, if this was helpful, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is a more efficient way, meanwhile try this solution:

```
for commo in df.market.unique():
    df.loc[df.market==commo,'lag_1'] = df.loc[df.market==commo,'commodity'].shift(1)
    df.loc[df.market==commo,'median_20'] = pd.rolling_median(df.loc[df.market==commo,'commodity'],20)
```

Comment: Thanks @user7235865. The first statement inside for-loop works fine. However the second statement - `df.loc[df.market==commo,'median_20'] = ...` throws `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'rolling'`. I think this error might be related to old version of pandas but in my office we use version '0.16.2' of pandas and unfortunately it is not easy to upgrade it in our production env. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: @Gerry: Try this new version with  `pd.rolling_median`

Comment: that is what I ended up using and it works. Thanks. For-loop is extremely slow for large data frame.

Comment: Also, `df.loc[df.market==commo,'median_20']...` statement is not median till last but includes the current row as well. One way to fix this would be to apply `shift(1)` to `median_20` column as well.